# How do I create query in sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need final result:

[image]

I used

```
max(value) OVER (PARTITION BY name order by value)
```

but is not support in sql server 2008 r2

in result
 first : 'a' because max value and next record all 'a'

second : 'd' because second  max value and next record all 'd'

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results. Also, what have you tried so far and what is not working?

Comment: "but is not working" tells us nothing: error? unexpected results? or something else?

Comment: not support order by in PARTITION BY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT name, MAX(value) AS max_value
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY name
),
WITH cte2 AS (
    SELECT t.name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.max_value DESC) rn
    FROM cte1 t
)
SELECT t1.name, t1.value
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN cte2 t2
    ON t1.name = t2.name
ORDER BY t2.rn, t1.value DESC
```

Comment: @Saber `not true result` ... what does that comment even mean?  Update your question clearly showing the input and output you want.  My answer meets the diagram you showed us.

Comment: in result first : 'a' because max value and next record all 'a' 
second : 'd' because second max value and next record all 'd'

Comment: tank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a weird requirement, but the below code snippet should do your work -

```
declare @t table(name varchar(1), value int)
insert into @t values('a',50),('b',11),('a',10),('d',33),('f',5),('b',3)
select name,value from @t
select name,value from @t order by case when name='a' then 1 when name='b' then 3 when name='d' then 2 when name='f' then 4 end,value desc
```